# Copy dropdown table from internet VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy a table from this website: http://www.nzfma.org/data/search.aspx#

I need to select the date as yesterday's date, then copy and paste the table to a file.

My code is below:

```
Sub Test1()

'open IE, navigate to the website of interest and loop until fully loaded

Dim NZFMA As Worksheet
Dim TodayN As Range
Dim elemCollection As Object


Set NZFMA = Sheets("NZFMA")
Set TodayN = NZFMA.Range("B2")

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

With ie
    .Visible = True
    .navigate "http://www.nzfma.org/data/search.aspx"

    Do Until Not ie.Busy And ie.ReadyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop        

    'Select the dates from the drop-down box
    ie.Document.getElementbyid("ctl00_cphBody_rdpDate_dateInput").Value =     Format(TodayN, "yyyy-mm-dd")

    'Click the submit button
    ie.Document.getElementbyid("cphBody_btnSearch").Value = "Search"

    'Copy the results
    Set elemCollection = ie.Document.getElementbyid("cphBody_upResults")

    While ie.ReadyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Wend

End With

End Sub
```

For some reason, my macro stops after the first getElementbyID line. Can someone advise as to which part of the code is wrong?

Comment: any errors?  ie.Document.getElementbyid("cphBody_btnSearch").Click

Comment: I have tried, there is no error, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, haven't tested this but something like it should work to change the first dropdown box

```
Dim elemCollection As HTMLFormElement
set elemCollection =  ie.Document.getElementbyid("cphBody_lstMarket")
dim teststring as string

teststring = whatever

Select Case TestString
    Case "BKBM"
        elemCollection.selectedIndex = 1
    Case "BBRS030"
        elemCollection.selectedIndex = 2
```

etc etc

To change the date, you will need something like

```
ie.Document.getElementbyid("ctl00_cphBody_rdpDate_dateInput")(0).value = "05/07/2016"
```

Anyway, have a go with that, and please tell me the results

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. i have tried the code, but it's not working. It's giving me automation error.

Comment: teststring = whatever... need to change that whatever to something you are testing.

and you need to extend the select case.